# How to find next date from time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know is it possible in mysql query.. when I say give me date when it is 9am.. the return answer is depends upon current time when it is 8am it give me today's date. when it is 10pm it gives me tomorrow date. how it is possible in mysql query.

Comment: what is your sample table structure with values ? and what is the required output based on that ?

Comment: I have a shedule of classes for example 11:00 pm without date I want to give it date to closest class

Comment: This kind of problem normally relates to timezones. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURTIME(), ':', 1)` to get the hours of current time.

As I understood you want to get tomorrow date, if it is 10pm or later

Example given:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURTIME(), ':', 1) >= 22
THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ELSE CURDATE()
END
```

Source: http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_dates.asp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hour value from a given datetime expression, using [HOUR](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_hour.asp) function. [CURDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp)() function is used to return the current date. You can add/subtract 'integers' to it get the date corresponding to current date +/- 'integer days' . Assuming that the time >= 10 pm returns next day:

```
SELECT IF(HOUR(`datetime_field`) > 22, CURDATE(), CURDATE() + 1);
```

Comment: @Artier happy to help :) You may accept this as an answer ! for others to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just add 2 hours

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR));
```

This will then return tomorrow’s date for anytime after 10pm.